# Subgroup lattice of UT(3,3)

Tags: finite-groups, gap

I need to draw a subgroup lattice of $ UT(3,\mathbb{Z_{3}}) $, the group of upper triangular matrices with diagonal one.
How to do it? And whether there is somebody ready image? 
(I know that it can xgap but I have a problem with installing on windows)

Comment: Which group do you denote by $UT$? Upper triangular matrices?

Comment: Yes. It is the unitriangular matrix group of degree three over the field of three elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot run xgap, there is a GAP function `DotFileLatticeSubgroups` that outputs a graphical description of a subgroup lattice the http://www.graphviz.org format which presumably has a viewer program for Windows. For example

```
gap> s:=SylowSubgroup(SL(3,3),3);
<group of 3x3 matrices of size 27 over GF(3)>
gap> DotFileLatticeSubgroups(LatticeSubgroups(s),"tmp.dot");
```

produces a file that creates this picture:

[image: Graphviz-produced lattice]

The first number of a subgroup is the conjugacy class, the second the number within the class. Normal subgroups just have a single number.

Answer (score 1):

The group in question is the finite Heisenberg group $H_3(3)$ of order $27$. Its subgroup lattice can be computed with GAP, or similar programs. The group is nilpotent of class $2$. $H_3(p)$ has $p^2+2p+4$ subgroups, so $H_3(3)$ has $19$ subgroups.

Reference: The [wiki-page](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_unitriangular_matrix_group:UT(3,p)).