# Library of posets in GAP?

Tags: order-theory, gap, sagemath

Is there a way to obtain in GAP the Hasse diagrams of famous posets like the partition lattice or the divisor lattice of an integer? If they are not saved, is there a way to get them somehow else, like with using SAGE?
If not, is there a trick to obtain the Hasse diagram easily without programming everything from the start?
Are small posets or lattice saved in GAP? Like the ones with at most 7 points.

Comment: I suggest to look at FindStat, especially http://www.findstat.org/Posets. See also https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.3690

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov thanks, so in GAP (or a GAP package) alone no librarys or similar things exist for posets?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You may ask the [GAP Forum](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html) in case someone may have it (perhaps in some list encoding, since GAP has now such data type, but hopefully readable in GAP then). I have listed some standalone mathematical databases [here](https://github.com/alex-konovalov/gnu/wiki/Mathematical-databases) - will be interested to add it to the list, if it exists.

Answer (score 5):

Sage has a built-in `Poset` class with pretty broad functionality.  [This Sage cell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwLULBVKMgvTi0p1jDV5OVKyy9SKFDIzFMIsOLlUgCCAr3ijPxyDU0orygzr0RDPSZPXRMAuxsO9Q==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) gives a pretty boring example:

```
P = posets(5)
for p in P:
    p.show()
    print('\n')
```

For something more specific, you can look at the [catalog of posets/lattices](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/posets/poset_examples.html) and use some of the [graph plotting options](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plotting/sage/graphs/graph_plot.html):

```
posets.IntegerPartitions(10).hasse_diagram().show(figsize=[10,10])
```

[image: partitions of 10 as lattice]

For a better experience you'll probably want to be more sophisticated with the plot options, such as using this option:

> `heights` A dictionary mapping heights to the list of vertices at this height.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the specific question: No, GAP has no formal ``poset'' data type and thus also does not have a library of posets. However it is likely that such a library exists as a standalone resource on the web.

Comment: and for lattices?

Answer (score 2):

Although GAP has no formal poset data type, the [homology](http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Jean-Guillaume.Dumas/Homology/) package does have such a type, and has some of the examples that you speak of built-in.  It's difficult to build the compiled portion of the library, but pretty much all of the poset stuff should work without compiling.  Unfortunately, I don't think the poset support in this package is hooked up to anything that will display Hasse diagrams.

There are two ways I know of to display Hasse diagrams of subgroup lattices in GAP, both requiring some additional software:

It's not too difficult to display Hasse diagrams in [xgap](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/xgap.html) or [Gap.app](https://cocoagap.sourceforge.io/).  The built-in code handles only subgroup lattices.  I have (unpolished) code that draws partition lattices in these systems.  For what it's worth, I'll [post it to my webpage](http://osebje.famnit.upr.si/~russ.woodroofe/partition-lat.g).  It at least will serve as a model for how to display Hasse diagrams of new posets in xgap or Gap.app.

Note that you need Xwindows (on Linux or other Unix-like system) to run xgap, or a Mac to run Gap.app.

You could also look at the routine DotFileLatticeSubgroups.  That exports a subgroup lattice to a GraphViz file, which you can then turn into a picture of the Hasse diagram.  See e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737962/subgroup-lattice-of-ut3-3/1737987).

Answer (score 2):

It does, it's mentioned in `Macaulay2`'s docs [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.15/share/doc/Macaulay2/Posets/html/_gap__Convert__Poset.html)

> The GAP package `Simplicial Homology`, available at [http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~dumas/Homology/](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Edumas/Homology/), provides methods for using posets within GAP. According to the documentation, posets are stored in GAP in the following manor: The ground set is the set of integers 1..n+1 and the relations are stored in a list of length n, where the ith entry is the set of vertices which cover i in the poset. In particular, 1 should be the unique minimal element and n+1 should be the unique maximal element.

The link is now dead, and seems to be https://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Jean-Guillaume.Dumas/Homology/ instead now. You can find the old link on [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20080512090914/http://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Edumas/Homology/).

Note that this is *not* the `simpcomp` package.

I'm looking into the same problem and didn't know about the `heights` parameter in Sage, I'll probably use that instead but leaving this note in case it helps.

Specifically, I was trying to see if it was simple to make an integer partition lattice like it is in Sage, but it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Thanks for finding this! The package has never been submitted for the redistribution with GAP (I don't recollect all the details, but installing it seemed highly non-trivial). It may be worth checking how it is compatible with GAP 4.11, maybe also try to provide it in a Docker container based on https://hub.docker.com/r/gapsystem/gap-docker/ ...